# How to modify the sender name in AIX mail command

Tags: aix

I am supposed to modify the sender name in AIX mail command to something like this : "Centralised Operations support" instead of this format : @sever-name.
I used this command : cat $MailBody | mail -s "Test mail" .

I tried using the -r option with the mail command but it is not accepting spaces .

cat $MailBody | mail -s "Test mail"  -r "Centralised Operations Support"
Operations... User unknown
support... User unknown

Also the to list also contains many unnecessary users coming up apart from the one which i supplied.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the -r option on AIX's `mail` is only for setting the sender e-mail. I kinda remember, however, that if you set the sender e-mail to `<account on your server>@<your server's FQDN>`, and then you set that user's name on `smit`, it is possible to use names with spaces on the sender field.